# Scrolling on ancher tags & scrolling performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mobile

I have an `angular` web app that builds a list of events for my users. When I scroll through the list with my finger on a mobile device & start the scroll on an anchor tag it will redirect me, is there a way to prevent this from happening? Perhaps putting a delay to see if its a drag before redirecting.

Also is there a way to make my scroll feel more like an app from the scroll speed and smoothness. When I go on apps like Facebook and scroll it just has such a satisfying scrolling speed.

Comment: If `touchstart` on an anchor goes to its href, that means this special behaviour is implemented in your app. Then the question is not "how to prevent it" but "where is it implemented in my app". Scroll smoothness depends on browser, device, styles (avoid text shadows on slow mobile devices), javascript scroll event listeners ... Slowness might be in your app.